# Ansible - how pass boolean to role?

Tags: ansible

I am struggling to call a role that would depend on a specific value. Currently my playbook contains:

```
- name: "sandbox"
  hosts: "showroom:local"
  become: true
  become_user: "root"
  pre_tasks:
    - name: suicide test
      debug:
        var: branch_stop_suicide
    - debug:
        var: git_branch
    - debug:
        msg: git_branch not in branch_stop_suicide
  roles:
    - role: server-suicide
      server_suicide_active: git_branch not in branch_stop_suicide
```

In debug I can see following results:

```
TASK [suicide test] **********************************************
ok: [52.59.218.32] => {
    "branch_stop_suicide": [
        "ADHOC-add-showroom-termination-role-test-17", 
        "integration", 
        "master"
    ]
}
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [52.59.218.32] => {
    "git_branch": "ADHOC-add-showroom-termination-role-test-17"
}
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [52.59.218.32] => {
    "msg": "git_branch not in branch_stop_suicide"
}
```

This already shows a problem because `git_branch not in branch_stop_suicide` is considered a string instead of test if one variable is in another.

As a result my role receives string instead of boolean and fails to execute proper logic. How can I force evaluation of condition here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the check you are writing so it is evaluated like so:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ git_branch not in branch_stop_suicide }}"
```

This will result in the boolean you are expecting.

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": false
}
```